# MapServer reading SQL from 8-bits data type TIFF

Tags: raster, openlayers, mapserver, geotiff-tiff

I'm converting to SQL (PostGIS) some raster files (TIFF). Then I'm using those SQL files for queries with MapServer, and displaying it in my app with OpenLayers with no problems. Everything goes well. The TIFF files are like 600KB weight (by the way, the SQL files are like 22MB approx), and I can see with the QGIS explorer that they are Float64 as "Data Type" and -1.7e+308  as "No Data Values" (excuse me if the translations isn't OK, I'm using QGIS in Spanish). As I said, everything is OK.

In MapServer, I have a map file like this:

```
LAYER
    NAME zonificacion_cabernet_sauvignon_actual_rango5

    TYPE raster
    STATUS ON
    DATA "PG:host=192.168.1.133 port=5432 dbname='XXXXXX' user='postgres' password='XXXXXX' schema='raster' table='XXXXXX' mode='2' where='ano=2014 AND rango_5' "

    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:32719"
    END
    PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
    OPACITY 80
    CLASS
        NAME ""
        EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 1)
        COLOR "#3399cc"
    END
    CLASS
        NAME ""
        EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 2)
        COLOR "#99cc33"
    END
    CLASS
        NAME ""
        EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 3)
        COLOR "#cc3399"
    END
END
```

Everything goes well, I can see 3 colors (each for those cases) in the map of my app.

But now, my client, who provides this TIFF files, made a change, and he told me "I will use Integer instead Float". So, I started to replace the SQL files, doing all the previous actions. The TIFF files now are much lighter, they are around 60-70KB and the SQL files like 2MB, but the script on the map file is not working, but if I use this:

`EXPRESSION` it does:

```
CLASS
    NAME ""
    EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 85)
    COLOR "#3399cc"
END
CLASS
    NAME ""
    EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 170)
    COLOR "#99cc33"
END
CLASS
    NAME ""
    EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 255 )
    COLOR "#cc3399"
```

I checked with QGIS Explorer the new TIFFs, and I can see that "Data Type" is now "Byte - Natural Integer of 8 bits" and "No Data Values" are `255`

What should I do to my client in order to have TIFF files with correct data? because I need to match the `EXPRESSION`with 1, 2 and 3 (the amount of pixels for each color) but not 85, 170 and 255.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question?

Comment: Finally, the tif files were in Byte, Mapserver couldn't handle it. My client now save them as 32 Integer, and now it's recognizing my `EXPRESSION`